# OneToMany Mapping Child Parent

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, hibernate-onetomany

Hi I am using Spring Boot app with MVC. I have two model classes Parent and Child. Parent to Child has OnetoMany Mapping. I have a form submit in which I'm passing few fields of child class, now what is happening when I bind the child class in the controller method is that it picks up the id of Parent class and binds it automatically to Child object in Controller.Please suggest what I am missing in here.

Following is the code for the same:

```
@PostMapping("/{id}/child")
    public String editChildPOST(@PathVariable Long id, 
            Child child, Model model, BindingResult errors, 
            Principal principal) {

        logger.info("editChildPOST: " + child.getId);
        model.addAttribute("aaaa", aaaa);
        model.addAttribute("bbbb", "bbbb");
        return "redirect:/xxxx";
    }
```

Following is the mapping in the parent Class :

```
class Parent{
@OneToMany(cascade= ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private List<Child> child;
}
```

SO in debug mode if I try to check the value of child in Controller it shows Child Id as parent's Id although I haven't set Child Id anywhere in the form submit.

Comment: Show more code, like the full Parent class instead of just snippet, the Child class too.

Comment: Is the relationship between Parent and Child Unidirectional or Bidirectional ?

Comment: it is unidirectional